# How to calculate the diameter of a moving circle from afar while lacking and knowing some information?

Tags: speed, distance, perception, length

Let's say there is a solid wood wheel with two tires attached at the bottom travelling on a level road towards me while facing me width-wise (as in, the side of it from which you can see its diameter). I take a few camera shots of said wheel as it is moving.

I do not know its actual diameter, and do not know the distance between me and the wheel, but, I do know the speed it is travelling at, the field of view, and its angular diameter in each shot.

Comment: Anyone else got an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the speed, after known time you get a known distance traveled. Does your camera time stamp the photos? Compare that distance in your frame to the wheel diameter.

Comment: No, it does not time stamp the photos.

Comment: Then you need to either take a video, knowing the number of frames per second, or record the time between pictures.

Comment: Is there really no other way around this?

Comment: You are trying to get the scale of the photo.  As you said you knew the speed I was trying to use it to set the scale.  If you have an object of known size in the photo, like a person, you can use that to set the scale.  Otherwise, I don't see a way to distinguish a small near object from a large far one.

Comment: So, you're saying that, if, in each photo, I had a person of a known height who is close enough to the camera to have their body fully shown and nothing more, by somehow comparing his height to the circle's diameter as it approaches, I could calculate its real size?

Comment: No, you want a person at the same distance from the camera as the wheel.  Then you can just scale the diameter of the wheel from their height.  If they are six feet tall and the wheel is half as tall as they are, the wheel is three feet in diameter.